# why is a purely percentage wrapper not working?

Tags: html, css

I have trouble to understand why the use of percentages is not working in this case: Could somebody enlighten me?

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you also put this CSS code?

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: by default, the html and body elements have no defined width; 90% of `undefined` isn't going to get you anywhere. By setting `html` and `body` to have `100%` widths, the width setting on your wrapper will now work

Comment: @jackwanders - you have confused height with width. You do not need to have a base width in a parent element for width as a percentage to work within child elements. You do however need a base height set to be able to use height as a percentage in the immediate children

Answer (score 0):

The width will take a percentage of the parent container. If you did not set a width on the body element, then the width is 0. To solve your problem:

```
body {width:100%;}
#wrapper {width:90%}
```

This results in a div 90% of total width of the screen.